# Selinium webdriver C# Not able to enter text in the text field using

Tags: selenium

I am not able to enter text in the text box field using selenium webdriver C# and IE11. It opened the URL and clicked on the login button but it's not entering the username.

My code to enter text in the username textbox field is

```
IWebElement myField = driver.FindElement(By.Id(“Loginlogin”));
myField.SendKeys("sandy");
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" name="Login" action="lg01.asp?ccsForm=Login">
   <table class="RecordImpac" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr class="Controls">
         <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="Controls">
         <td valign="top">
            <input id="Loginlogin" maxlength="100" size="30" value="" name="login">
            <br>
         </td>
      </tr>
```

Env:

```
Browser IE11
IE webdriver server: IEDriverServer_x64_2.47.0
Visual Studio 2015 community
```

Answer (score 1):

I could successfully send the text to username textbox. Code is in Java. You can convert to C# accordingly. Try putting some implicit wait.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","pathtoiedriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("location/test_html.html");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.id("Loginlogin")).sendKeys("sandy");
```